# The most simple way to get the value of a registry key

Tags: c#, .net, registry

Is it possible to get a value of a "registry key" without parsing the path to the registry?

What I am actually looking for is a one liner command to get the value of a key like:

```
object value = Registry.GetValue("path");
```

The "path", for example, is:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Install

The `Install` key is actually the value.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
object value = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full", "Install", null);
```

So question, is it possible to get the value of a registry key without parsing the path?

Thanks!

Comment: The registry is a big place. And your current solution's already a one-liner :P

Comment: Great. But even microsoft doesnt recommend using registry as storage. App_Data, .config is MUCH better, more maintainable and more functional.

Comment: @BoltClock: LOL. No, but I have to parse the last key in the path to get the "value". The data is coming from an XML file that I have no control so I am forced to "massage" it. I'm asking if there is a way to get a value from a "key" without "massaging" the key into to two parts.

Comment: @Ilya Smagin: I'm pretty sure Ian just wants to retrieve system values from the registry, not use it as storage for his application.

Comment: Could you extend your question with an explanation of why you want this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to parse the key name and value name yourself, the `Path` class can do it for you:

```
static object GetRegistryValue(string fullPath, object defaultValue)
{
    string keyName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    string valueName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    return Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware that the Path class can also work on Registry keys! Thanks!

Comment: @Ian, actually it doesn't know anything about the registry, it just works on strings that represent paths ;)

Comment: note that this will return null if the key doesn't exist. May want to check for null and return defaultValue in that case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Registry.LocalMachine` for HKLM. You can get some ideas here http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/ :-)

Comment: This will only work if the key is in HKLM. It is not always the case. I don't want to parse out the root.